# How to download external .VTT with <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a button that when is clicked, it downloads a external .vtt file. I have this code:

```
<a href="https://bitflix-subs.herokuapp.com/subs/tt2935510/0" download>Download</a>
```

But when is clicked, it redirects me to the page and download doesn't starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and wow its working

```js
function downloadSubs(){
$.ajax({
 url: "https://bitflix-subs.herokuapp.com/subs/tt2935510/0", 
  success: function(result){
    var dataStr = "data:text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(result);
    var dlAnchorElem = document.getElementById('downloadAnchorElem');
    dlAnchorElem.setAttribute("href",dataStr);
    dlAnchorElem.setAttribute("download", "test.vtt");
    dlAnchorElem.click();
  }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="downloadAnchorElem" style="display:none"></a>


<H1> Click dowload button <H1>

<button onclick="downloadSubs()">Download Subs</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob) download and [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

```html
<a name="dl" id="dl" download="download.vtt" target=_blank>clicky click</a>

<script>
fetch('https://bitflix-subs.herokuapp.com/subs/tt2935510/0')
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok)
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok')
        return response.blob()
    })
    .then(blob => {
        blob.type = 'text/vtt'
        let b = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
        document.getElementById('dl').href = b
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('There has been a problem with your fetch operation:', error)
    });

// to clean up
//URL.revokeObjectURL(document.getElementById('dl').href);
</script>
```

See also [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) reference.

Answer (score 0):

You cant manually download a vtt file from a html type page. The only thing you can do is:

```
<a href="bitflix-subs.herokuapp.com/subs/tt2935510/0" download>Download</a>
```

With this change it will try to download a html page which you can manually change to a .vtt file with some javascript

I hope this helped you!

Comment: no I removes the http:// section so it actually downloads the file instead of doing nothing :)

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm not sure if relative resolution is valid HTML and it does not workin FF at least or when your document is in `file:///` schema.